Whitelabel error page with 403 Forbidden after upgrading from Spring Boot 2.0 to 3.0
Ever since I've upgraded my Spring Boot version from 2.0 to 3.0. I'm getting a whitelabel error page with the following message:
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Thu Jul 11 12:50:49 CEST 2024
There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403).
Forbidden

But if I enter the URL http://localhost:8080/application/ and navigate to /admin or any other defined path in securityFilterChain, it opens normally without any issues.
I can't pinpoint what exactly is wrong. Below is the relevant code (SecurityConfiguration) file.
package de.example.application.config;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey;

import com.vaadin.flow.spring.security.RequestUtil;
import de.bmg.kraftfahrer.utils.ApplicationConstants;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;

import org.springframework.security.saml2.core.Saml2X509Credential;
import org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.registration.InMemoryRelyingPartyRegistrationRepository;
import org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.registration.RelyingPartyRegistration;
import org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.registration.RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository;
import org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.registration.RelyingPartyRegistrations;
import org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.web.DefaultRelyingPartyRegistrationResolver;
import org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.web.RelyingPartyRegistrationResolver;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Value("${saml.idpURL}")
    private String idpMetadataURL;

    @Value("${spring.security.saml2.relyingparty.registration.sp.entity-id}")
    private String entityId;

    @Value("${spring.security.saml2.relyingparty.registration.sp.acs.location}")
    private String acsLocation;

    @Value("${saml.registrationid}")
    String registrationId;

    boolean securityDebug;

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, RequestUtil requestUtil) throws Exception {
        http.csrf(cfg -> cfg.ignoringRequestMatchers(requestUtil::isFrameworkInternalRequest));
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                .requestMatchers("/user/*").hasAnyRole(ApplicationConstants.APPLICATION_USER.toString())
                .requestMatchers("/admin/*").hasAuthority(ApplicationConstants.APPLICATION_ADMIN.toString())
                //.requestMatchers("/error").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
        ).saml2Login(saml2 -> {});

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    RelyingPartyRegistrationResolver relyingPartyRegistrationResolver(RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository registrations) {
        return new DefaultRelyingPartyRegistrationResolver(id -> registrations.findByRegistrationId(registrationId));
    }

    @Bean
    RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository repository(@Value("classpath:saml/idpbmg.pkcs8") RSAPrivateKey privateKey) {
        Saml2X509Credential signing = Saml2X509Credential.signing(privateKey, relyingPartyCertificate());

        RelyingPartyRegistration relyingPartyRegistration = RelyingPartyRegistrations
                .fromMetadataLocation(idpMetadataURL).entityId(entityId).assertionConsumerServiceLocation(acsLocation)
                .registrationId(registrationId).signingX509Credentials(credentials -> credentials.add(signing)).build();
        return new InMemoryRelyingPartyRegistrationRepository(relyingPartyRegistration);
    }

     X509Certificate relyingPartyCertificate() {
        Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("saml/idpbmg.cer");
        try (InputStream is = resource.getInputStream()) {
            return (X509Certificate) CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509").generateCertificate(is);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException(ex);
        }
    }
}



I have checked my security configuration but couldn't identify the issue.
The endpoints mapping seems to work fine when accessed directly.

When entering the URL http://localhost:8080/application/admin/, it should not display a whitelabel eror page but rather the expected page.

But if I enter the URL "http://localhost:8080/application/" and navigate to "/admin" What is the resulting URL?

then the resulting URL works correctly and I don't understand why is this happening

What is the resulting URL?
